# Android: Constraint Layout - Unable to Adjust View bounds of an image view after ratio resize

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using a ConstraintLayout.

I have an image view which I want to be 16:9. And below this Image View I am trying to place a text view.

Now when the image view is set to gone, it is expected that the Text View would get shifted up. But this not happening.

Could some one please try to figure out the issue in my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/dark_background"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    tools:layout_width="300dp"
    tools:layout_height="300dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="The is the test that does not seem to work"
        android:layout_marginTop="12.41dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginTop="0dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: anyone please??

Answer (score 0):

I think that the behavior you are seeing is what is designed into `ConstraintLayout`. It seems counter intuitive that a `gone` view should seem to take up any space, but in comment #8 from [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228151) on the issue tracker this statement is made:

> @herrbert74 no, tadej is correct -- this is indeed a bug. In this example where the view is constrained on all sides and goes to gone, it should resolves to a point -- but constraints should still be respected. Meaning, in this case it should be at the center of all the constraints. Currently, the widget only set its size to zero, which works on single constraints, but doesn't on dual constraints. Beta 5 will have the correct behavior.

If I understand this correctly, when the `View` is made `gone` and it is constrained on the top and the bottom, as yours is, then the `View` shrinks to nothing (a point) but its constraints are still respected. In other words, the `View` becomes a point near the center of the layout. Your text view has a top constraint to the bottom of the `ImageView` which takes up zero space but that zero space sits in the middle of the layout.

So, that doesn't really help, but it does explain what's going on.

One way to do what you are trying to do would be to remove the bottom constraint on the `ImageView` when you make the `ImageView` `gone`. Without the bottom constraint, the `ImageView` will float to the top of the layout and take the `TextView` with it.